# Javers store value object as individual document cause 'skip' and 'limit' not working as expected

Tags: java, javers

I have an entity that contain one value object. When saving this entity for the first time, I can see that Javers store two initial records inside *jv_snapshots*. One for **Person** and one for **Address**. I am using Javers 3.8.0 and Spring Boot integration with Mongo repository.

Is it possible that when we store this initial records or subsequent updates, value object is nested inside the main entity instead of creating individual record ? Since when I use *limit* and *skip*, for pagination, it being counted as two instead of one record.

```
public class Person {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private Address address;

  //getter setter ommited
}

// on another file
public class Address {
  private String city
  //getter setter ommited
}
```

Here is the query that I used to retrieve the changes, here I am expecting 5 different snapshots, if I made 5 changes on same Person entity, but because the reason I describe above, I am getting less than 5 snapshot.

```
javers.findChanges(
    QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(documentId, Person.class)
                .withChildValueObjects()
                .limit(5)
                .build())
```

Answer (score 0):

In JaVers, each object (Value Object or Entiy) is always persisted with its own Snapshot. There are no nested snapshots. If you are querying for Entities withChildValueObjects, these Value Objects *consume* the owerall snapshot limit.